# R8 minify: Type defined multiple times

Tags: android, android-room, android-r8

When building a signed release APK I'm getting following error:

```
.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/532a317ccd54c8ae4f622faeb8b534a9/jetified-wordup-core-0.2.1-runtime.jar:de/codereddev/wordup/database/WordDao_Impl$5.class,
Type de.codereddev.wordup.database.WordDao_Impl$5 is defined multiple times:
/home/codered_dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/532a317ccd54c8ae4f622faeb8b534a9/jetified-wordup-core-0.2.1-runtime.jar:de/codereddev/wordup/database/WordDao_Impl$5.class,
/home/codered_dev/MySoundboardApp/app/build/intermediates/javac/release/classes/de/codereddev/wordup/database/WordDao_Impl$5.class
```

This Room DAO definition comes from a [library](https://github.com/CodeRedDev/WordUp) I created myself.

Looking into the `.jar` file I can find this:

[image]

This only happens on release. I can still build and run debug without any problems.

Unfortunately I can't find the error. Hopefully anyone here might have a hint for me.

I first assumed it might be due to the fact that the library contains a standard definition of a Room database and my application using the library contains its own custom definition holding the same DAOs. So annotation processors would maybe process the DAOs twice. But I couldn't check this properly.

If it's important to know: I'm also using Koin for dependency injection.

Comment: Hi, I work on the R8 team, and have a question. The message you have quoted above (`Type de.codereddev.wordup.database.WordDao_Impl$5 is defined multiple times:
/home/codered_dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/532a317ccd54c8ae4f622faeb8b534a9/jetified-wordup-core-0.2.1-runtime.jar:de/codereddev/wordup/database/WordDao_Impl$5.class,`) ends with a `,`. There should be a reference to the second class where the definition was also found. Can you double-check if there is a second class reference in the error message?

Comment: @sgjesse I've edited my post to the extended error message.

Comment: The update shows that the class `de.codereddev.wordup.database.WordDao_Impl$5` is in 1) the dependency `jetified-wordup-core-0.2.1-runtime` and in the app code itself `app/build/intermediates/javac/release/classes/de/codereddev/wordup/database/WordDao_Impl$5.class`. For R8 there can be no duplicate classes. Most likely you will need to not have DAOs defined twice.

Comment: Could it be that because in the framework there is a `RoomDatabase` (RD) definition containing a getter for the DAO aswell as the app has it's own definition of a RD that also contains the getter for the DAO?

Otherwise this wouldn't make sense as there is no definition of the DAO class in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't exactly know the reason but I got the library working by removing the Room kaptCompiler from the library and instead only have it in the app that is using the library.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the same package is used by different modules, e.g. a library and the app using the library both using `org.foo.bar` as package. If different packages are used, the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem:

In my `lib-base`, I have a `WordDao`(baseDatabase),

```
abstract fun dao(): WordDao
```

but in my `module-word`(wordDatabase), there is also one

```
abstract fun dao(): WordDao
```

So, after I delete the `abstract fun dao(): WordDao` in `module-word`,I solved this problem