# Duplicate DatabindingComponent class found while generating bundle

Tags: java, data-binding, android-databinding, androidx, android-r8

I get this error when i try to generate App Bundle for release.

Component used:
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

Version used:
Android studio 4.1

:app:minifyReleaseWithR8 FAILED
/Users/androiddeveloper/Documents/udux_android/app/build/intermediates/module_and_runtime_deps_classes/release/base.jar: R8: Type androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent is defined multiple times: /Users/androiddeveloper/Documents/udux_android/app/build/intermediates/module_and_runtime_deps_classes/release/base.jar:androidx/databinding/DataBindingComponent.class, /Users/androiddeveloper/Documents/udux_android/livestream/build/intermediates/module_and_runtime_deps_classes/release/feature-livestream.jar:androidx/databinding/DataBindingComponent.class

- I am wondering if this should even happen as the documentation says databinding should be enabled in all modules.
- I have tried to use `dontnote` in app's proguard's file but still doesnt solve the issue

**Edit**
\ni have found an issue relating to this but for another class

- [R8 minify: Type defined multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63099092/5706425)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on two modules separately and when i decided to merged the tow modules into the main app. the DFM module had it on Databinding component class which somehow i felt was autogenerated.

I ended up deleted the package androidx.databinding.Databinding component on the module and that was what solved my issue.